# Windows Server 2012 RDP - session taken over by another

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a 2012 terminal server and have several users that use the same RDP credentials.  When one session is open and then another user uses the same credentials, it kicks off the first session.

Is there a way to keep the 2nd session from kicking off the first, or send them a message that a session is in progress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.  There are two methods:

1. Group Policy - Open gpedit.msc and navigate to `Computer Configuration\ Administrative Templates\ Windows Components\ Remote Desktop Services\ Remote Desktop Session Host\ Connections\`.  Set `Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session` to `Disabled`.
2. Registry - Using `regedit.exe`, navigate to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server`.  Set `fSingleSessionPerUser` to `REG_DWORD 0x00000000`.